# How to model a common response class in individual service projects in Springdoc Open API

Tags: openapi, springdoc

I'm trying to use Spring doc api, to  generate the open api document for my service project.

I have a common class Response class defined in another library and we don't have access to add/modify this class.

for e.g.

```
public class RestResponse implements Serializable {
    protected MetadataType metadata;
    protected List any;
    ......

}
```

This class will be used in multiple services (multiple projects) to generate the response, 'any' field in the RestResponse class is populated with the individual services business object.

How can i model the response class for each individual service using @Schema.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the answer: For the Ability to define different schemas for the same class

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/685

Your question is not related directly to springdoc, but to swagger usage.